# How to get Near IBeacon latitude and longitude in building?

Tags: ios, swift, ibeacon, indoor-positioning-system

How to get nearest ibeacon latitude and longitude values in indoor position(in shopping mall). I can get nearest beacon accuracy(example <1m immediate) but i want that IBeacon position latitude and longitude. Can you post any sample code

thanks
Laxman

Comment: An iBeacon shouldn't give you its Latitude/Longitude. It's up to you (maybe through a WebService) to know the identify the iBeacon (major/minor/UUID) and know the latitude/longitude corresponding.

Comment: Building on what @Larme said, beacons don't know where they are unless you're attaching a GPS radio that works with it. What you COULD do is have the beacon transmit its lat/lon if they don't move and you program it to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Bluetooth **beacons are extremely simple devices that only transmit a unique identifier**.  **They have no idea what their latitude and longitude is**.

The typical approach to this problem is to **create a database or lookup table** that converts a beacon identifier to a latitude/longitude.  You would need to create this lookup table yourself, by finding the latitude and longitude of each point where you place a beacon.  Then, in your application code, when you determine that the mobile device is nearest to one of those beacons, you look up the latitude and longitude in this table.

There are several ways to look up the latitude and longitude for the beacon identifier:

1. Embed the lookup table in your app.  This is the simplest approach, but it requires you to update the app if you change the beacon identifiers or the positions of the beacons.
2. Use an off the shelf web service like [ProximityKit](http://proximitykit.radiusnetworks.com) that lets you attach arbitrary data like latitude and longitude to beacon and look it up automatically when detecting beacons.
3. Build your own web service that does the equivalent.

Full Disclosure:  I am Chief Engineer at Radius Networks, which hosts the ProximityKit service.